# Regex: Find tags that not contain word and insert that word on REPLACE

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have many links as this one:

`<a href="love-management.html" title="See this" class="external" rel="category tag">`

and this one

`<a href="https://abcd.com/love-management.html" title="See this" class="external" rel="category tag">`

Extract From:  `<td class="text_dreapta">On Feb 20, 2012, in <a href="love-management.html" title="See this" class="external" rel="category tag">Management</a>`

Now, it's about the first case. I need to find all those tags that do not contain `https://` and to insert on to insert it into.

So, basicaly:

`<a href="love-management.html"`

will become

`<a href="https://abcd.com/love-management.html"`

But, be carefully not to repeat `https://` such as `<a href="https://https://abcd.com/love-management.html"`

Comment: I doubt `https://love-management.html` is a valid url

Comment: right. I edit. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead to assert that there is not already a https://, so your Regex would look like `(<a .*?href=")(?!https://)(.+?")`.

Then it is simply a case of replacing by the first group followed by https:// followed by the second group: `$1https://$2`.

You can try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/7Amldk/3).

Comment: What if tag is like this : `<a class="external" href="love-management.html">` ?

Comment: Those weren't specified, but I will edit the Regex accordingly

Comment: thanks a lot AUsername. Works perfectly. Super. I edit my topic, so the link `https://` to become `https://abcd.com/` You can change it too.